# How do you perform an ordinary SQL query in akka to return JSON using spray and postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, scala, rest, akka

I'm trying to perform an SQL query using the following:

```
class ReportService(val databaseService: DatabaseService)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

  import databaseService._
  import databaseService.driver.api._
  import spray.json._

  def getNames(): Future[Seq[(Int, Int, Double, Double, String)]] = {
    val setup = DBIO.seq(
      sql"select * from names".as[(Int, Int, Double, Double, String)]
    )

    println(db.run(setup))
    db.run(setup)
  }
}
```

So i've added these to the boilerplate code for the sample [akka-http-rest](https://github.com/ArchDev/akka-http-rest)

Then I have a route:

```
  val route = pathPrefix("reports") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      get {
        complete(getNames().map(_.asJson))
      }
    }
}
```

When I run the route the JSON always ends up being empty, even though there are items in the table.

I'm just wondering how to actually do this properly so that it works?

Comment: Did you get any log from your app or postgres?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the mapper doesnt know how to map this touple into JSON.

I would recommend you to create serialize method, to convert this touple into case class:

```
case class Name(arg1: Int, arg2: Int, arg3: Double, arg4: Double, arg5: String)

def serialize(setup: (Int, Int, Double, Double, String)): Name =
    Name(setup._1, setup._2, setup._3, setup._4, setup._5)
```

Add an implicit conversion from `Name` to `JSON` in your routes:

```
implicit val nameFormat = jsonFormat5(Name)
```

And finally update your route to:

```
complete(getNames().map(serialize))
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid creating a case class to do this? I intentionally used a tuple so that I can easily create hundreds of methods for specific SQL queries that can easily be returned as JSON. Is there a way I can do this easily?

Comment: Mario, perhaps what I mean to say is if I have a getNames(query) method, where i can put in any query. can I get the result of the query as Json?

Comment: if you're using spray-json, Tuple1 to Tuple7 are being handled, so should not be the problem, and it should throw error if it does not know how to serialize